# How to clear a textbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, textbox

I'm a programming noob, so I'm not sure how this isn't working.

Whenever I clone, two problems appear.

1) this clones when I click the text box AND the button

2) text box keeps value of whatever I wrote in it prior

I have tried `val('')` and this current method but I have no idea why it doesn't work.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    $('.cloneitem:first').clone().appendTo('#container').val('');
  });
  document.getElementById('textbox').value = '';
});
```

```css
select:invalid {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="clone.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="+" />
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="cloneitem">
  <form>
    <select required>
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>How much?</option>
      <option value="S">A little</option>
      <option value="M">A good bit</option>
      <option value="L">A lot</option>
    </select>
    of
    <input type=text id=textbox>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `id`s are supposed to unique within the document. You've to change the id of the textbox in the cloned element. Also, you're setting the value only once, when the document is ready, you need to move the line inside the click handler.

Comment: Hi Kate, thanks for the reply. I don't understand what you mean by "the click handler". Can you provide an example please? I managed to get it to stop cloning values in the textbox with .find("input:text").val("") however.

Comment: `$('input').click(function() {...})` The function here is the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 $(function(){
 $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
  $('.cloneitem:first').clone().appendTo('#container').val('');
      $("#container div:last input[type=text]").val("");
   });
 });
```

Comment: Hello Sanklap, unfortunately this code doesn't work. It refuses to clone the textbox and selection list now.